PDF.js read incorrect texts
folks, I am using pdf-lib, pdf-dist to extract information from pdf file. now I am confused by two problems:

Two rows of a table are shown in FireFox, Edge or other commercial pdf reader at the bottom of page 23. however, while I reading it using pdf-lib, the two rows are positioned at the top of page 24.

I can see a text "5,1" at the specified table cell via commercial PDF reader, however, while using pdfjs, I read out "20,1" from the the corresponding area.


My parsing flow is: 
1.parse drawing actions of pdf to get horizontal and vertical lines 
2.assembly lines into tables( divid page into logical cells) 
3.read and assembly the text elements in cells into cell-string
the above logical is confirmed by the almost-correct result. all, except the second problem, is normal. Even the first problem is acceptable because the logical assembling process of the data is not influenced by the mounting postion of the two rows. The second problem is not acceptable.
The relevent code likes below:
1.load pdf   

import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.mjs'; 
const ...
export default async function loadPDF() {
    const data = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync(pdfPath));
    const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({
                data,
                cMapUrl: mapPath,
                cMapPacked: true
    }).promise;
    return pdf;
}
    
2. get text elements
    
export async function getTextElements(page, debug = false) {
    let { items } = await page.getTextContent();
    let textElements = items
        .filter(t => !isWatermark(t))  // by transform
        .map(({ str, width, height, transform }) => ({
            str, width, height,
            left: transform[4],
            right: transform[4] + width,
            bottom: transform[5],
            top: transform[5] + height
         }));
    if (debug) {
       fs.writeFileSync("debug.json",JSON.stringify(items)); 
    }
    return removePageNumer(textElements); // by position
}

After finding the 2nd problem, I added debug code into the function getTextElements to get the whole original text content into a file called "debug.json". After mannually parsing the json file, no "5,1" but "20,1" is found at the area. So I think that the getTextContent function gave me false elements.
Is there another way to get all texts of a page instead of getTextContent function? Or have I missed some style parsing, for example, visibility, z-index? (I am new hand for parsing pdf and don't know if there any analogous concepts exist).
I am sorry that I don't know how to upload pdf file or I have no permission to upload.

Furthermore, PDFs can claim that what looks like a 5.2 actually is a 20.2. Some PDFs are constructed to do so to make people doing text extraction run into issues. So we'd need the actual PDF to determine what really is the issue here.

@KJ, I use pdf-lib directly. All functions I use directly come from pdf-lib.  the code is " import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.mjs';".  however , there is also a "pdf-lib" of version ^1.17.1 installed in package.json. Frankly, I don't know clearly what's the relation between them. I am now just getting familiar in the namespace pdfjslib namespace. So I said I using them both.

@KJ  OMG! after seeing you comment, I checked my code again and I found that I have made an odd combination of pdf-dist and pdf-lib (^_^). To realize table extracting ability, I have tried to use quite a few libs and later I have forgotten that my modules reference different libs. Now there are two libs underlaid: pdfjs-dist and pdf-lib. It's also a bit amazing that they can work together, despite that my problems might stem from that.

I load, extract drawing areas using pdfjs-dist, and pass pdfPage object loaded by pdfjs-dist to pdf-lib to extract texts in specified areas. pdf-lib doesn't reject or report error and try to extract texts according bounding areas I give it. Now it's clear that I should rewrite text extracting module using pdfjs-dist. Thanks for your tip.

I have rewritten text extracting module using pdf-dist lib, however I get the same result.

@mkl I am now getting doubt that there might be some trap, intentional or unintentional, to keep from extracting text easily. However, since the commercial pdf viewer can do it correctly, why pdfjs lib can't?

There are multiple (well, two major) ways to allow text extraction from a PDF, either via information in the PDF font object (Encoding, ToUnicode map, information in the embedded font program, ...) or via a marked content property. When there are information given both ways, different programs may choose one or the other, Adobe Acrobat prefers the marked content property while many text extractors prefer the information in the font objects. See also this answer.

I think there are a few layers. After this short period of time I'd like to look into it.
